# Using CFSpreadsheet to insert values into Database

Tags: unix, oracle11g, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I'm having a hard time inserting data from a spreadsheet into an Oracle 11g table. CFSpreadsheet reads my file data successfully and returns a query result. However, I can't simply loop over it and insert the data into my table because the columns in the query are not necessarily in the same order as the columns in my INSERT statement. Is there an example on how to do this?

I have this:

```
<cfspreadsheet action="read" 
   src="#Trim(PathToExcelFile)#" 
   query="MyData" excludeheaderrow="true">
</cfspreadsheet>
```

Then I retrieve the columns:

```
<cfset metadata = getMetadata(MyData)>
<cfset colList = "">  
<cfloop index="col" array="#metadata#">
   <cfset colList = listAppend(colList, col.name)>
</cfloop>
```

This is where I'm stuck:

```
<cfoutput query="MyData" startRow="2">
     How can I do insert into a table here?????
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: An [INSERT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insert_(SQL)) statement allows you to specify which columns the values will be inserted into. What part are you having difficulty with?

Comment: You are correct, thanks for reminding me. I have 236 columns in the insert statement and wondering if there is an easier way to do it?

Comment: That is way too many columns for a single table IMO. That said, you have a list of the column names. Why cannot you use that?

Comment: First, if you can use a database bulk loader instead of ColdFusion, do so.  It's a better tool for the job.  Second, this is a situation where you have to be thorough.  You have to ensure you have the correct datatype for each column and that you are handling empty cells correctly.  If you are not doing so already, load your raw data to a staging table with all columns as varchar.  Transform as necessary in that staging table then write to your real tables from the staging tables.